# Android Studio problem with "TextView" Class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was running an app to get the Mac Address of the phone, i did the code and i have no errors in compiling, but if i click on main_activity there's an error under the preview: The following classes could not be found:

> - Textview (Change to TextView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML).

In fact I have no output.

That's MainActivity:

```
package com.example.app1;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvUIDS;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvUIDS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_uids);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    TelephonyManager telMan = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    sb.append("IMEI: " + telMan.getDeviceId() + "\n");

    sb.append("Android ID: " + Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID) + "\n");

    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    String mac_adr = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
    if (mac_adr != null) {
        sb.append("WLAN MAC Address: " + mac_adr + "\n");
    } else {
        sb.append("WLAN MAC Address: not supported on this device\n");
    }

    BluetoothAdapter ba = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (ba != null) {
        sb.append("Bluetooth Address: " + ba.getAddress() + "\n");
    } else {
        sb.append("Bluetooth Address: not supported on this device\n");
    }

    tvUIDS.setText(sb.toString());
}
}
```

and that's the activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Textview
    android:id="@+id/tv_uids"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mac Address" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

sorry but I'm a newbie in doing apps. How can I solve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The following classes could not be found: - Textview (Change to
>   TextView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

It means that you have incorrect tag or unrecognized tag in your xml. You have the following xml in activity_main.xml which is incorrect:

```
<Textview
    android:id="@+id/tv_uids"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mac Address" />
```

it should be:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_uids"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mac Address" />
```

The correct tag is `TextView` not `Textview`.

Comment: You're very welcome. I often do the same error. To err is human. Btw, if this answer solve your problem, please accept it as an accepted answer to close the question. ;)